# Failed to Install or run Ubuntu 22.04 virtual Machine on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I've been unable to use any of my Ubuntu VirtualBox VMs. Whether it's 20.04 or 22.04, previous VMs have lost their ability to log in. New VMs aren't even able to install the Operating system. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Virtualbox and tried using different .iso files.

This problem has persisted for around a month and its only getting worse. It first started with loss of performance, and now I can't even use my boxes.
I'm working on VirtualBox 6.1.34

["Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer" error on new VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzpJZ.png)

This is my first post so please let me know what extra information I need to provide. I really need to fix this.

Machine Specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-core Processor 3.4 GHz
- RAM: 16 GB
- Host System: Windows 10 home 64-bit ver 21H1

**UPDATE:**
I was able to finally get Ubuntu to boot up, run, and install. However, after a restart of the VM, I run back into the original problem. The VM freezes after login.

I've attached a picture that shows regular resource usage on ubuntu boot up. However, the CPU usage locks at 100% and the VM freezes. I'm not really sure what to do about this now.

[CPU lockup after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgg08.png)

Comment: What are your settings for the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: @lucki1000, 6Gb RAM and 4 cores for processor. The vdi is 100Gbs virtual size. Everything else is pretty much default.

Comment: 4 cores is obviously too much, 2 are more than adequate considering the actual CPU has only 6. The CPU lockups errors become then self-explanatory. At some point you changed the settings to increase the cores, haven't you? It's simply not possible to run a VM with such settings in this specific hardware. Regardless of the host OS something must freeze or crash if it suddenly looses access to two thirds of the CPU.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, The problem initially began when the box had only 2 cores. I made a new box with only 2 cores for processor and kept everything the same. the problem persists.

Maybe this is a hardware/resources problem?